# How can I use typewriter mode in sublime text4?

Tags: sublimetext

I hope to use typewriter mode similar to typora to keep the cursor in the center of the screen.I've used Typewriter, but it has a lot of bugs and often doesn't work.If someone have a better choose,tell me please.thank you.